# Are all my Ruby files in my Rails project stored on the server I specify? (eg. Puma, Webrick)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, server, puma

When I enter a URL into my browser, and it sends a request to the server (in this case, the host is salty-headland-18854.herokuapp.com), are all my Rails files stored at this host?

How does Puma come into play? I understand Puma to be a web server and I've included its gem. What is the distinction here between the host and Puma?

Does Heroku have a bunch of physical computers somewhere, that house my literal .rb files?

[Visual of my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kFi3.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the files, but pretty much the answer is yes. Heroku pulls down your app from the git repository specified (or you push it to Heroku's git repository) and Heroku has all the files from that. Without a security exploit, no one is able to access their source.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a Heroku Dyno as a Linux server with the complete Rails application. When it is launched for the first time, a linux server is built and the Rails application copied to it and the app server launched.

You code actually lives in the Github repository you have linked to Heroku. Persistant data is stored either in the database or an external file service such as S3.

It is possible to run commands on the Dynos using **heroku run**

[Reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)